# How is lower sum of refinement partition greater than lower sum of partition of [a,b]?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

How is the lower sum of refinement partition greater than the lower sum of the partition of [a,b]?
let f be abounded function on [a,b].If P$\subset$Q , then

L(f, P)$\leq$ L(f,Q)

I know when we do refinement of partition our answer of the area under curve becomes more precise to the actual value. But I am not able to construct the rigorous for the same.

let P be a partition of the closed interval [a,b],given by

P=$\{a=x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_n=b\}$ let Q be refinement of partition P with one more point u , such that

Q=$\{a=x_0,x_1,\ldots,x_i,u,x_{i+1},x_n=b\}$

and i don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: when you take an infimum over a big interval, and splitt that interval into two intervals, the infinimum may get larger on one of the intervals, while the total area stays the same

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1].$ If $P=\{0,1\},$ then $L(P,f)=0\cdot 1 =0.$ If $Q=\{0,1/2,1\},$ then $L(Q,f)= 0\cdot (1/2) + (1/2)\cdot (1/2) = 1/4.$ Thus $L(P,f) < L(Q,f).$ This one example should help in turning on the light switch.

Comment: @zhw I need to know one thing. 

$.$ Is the refinement of a partition or the partition itself of a closed interval $[a,b]$ necessarily a small 'closed' and 'bounded' sub-interval?